# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.DateTime' on datetime literal

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a MySQL database of game hosts which can run games of a specific set of gametypes. I have a linq statement which returns the host id, name and title + start time of the last game played on the host (if any).

```
context.HostConfigurations.Select (h => new HostStatus {
                id = h.IdHostConfigurations,
                hostname = h.Hostname,
                gameTitle = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation.Title : "-",
                gameStart = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart : DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
                gameStartFriendly = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart.ToString ("ddd HH:mm") : "-"
            }).ToList ();
```

Log output as follows:

```
INFO: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command Executed DbCommand (21ms) [Parameters=[@__nowMinus24Hrs_0='?' (DbType = DateTimeOffset), @__nowMinusTenMinutes_1='?' (DbType = DateTimeOffset)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `h`.`idHostConfigurations` AS `id`, `h`.`hostname`, CASE
    WHEN `h`.`idGamesLast` IS NOT NULL
    THEN `h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation`.`title` ELSE '-'
END AS `gameTitle`, CASE
    WHEN `h`.`idGamesLast` IS NOT NULL
    THEN `h.LastGameNavigation`.`gamestart` ELSE '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
END AS `gameStart0`, CASE
WHEN `h`.`idGamesLast` IS NOT NULL
    THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
END, `h.LastGameNavigation`.`gamestart`
FROM `HostConfigurations` AS `h`
LEFT JOIN `Games` AS `h.LastGameNavigation` ON `h`.`idGamesLast` = `h.LastGameNavigation`.`idGames`
LEFT JOIN `GameTypes` AS `h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation` ON `h.LastGameNavigation`.`idGameTypes` = `h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation`.`idGameTypes`

ERROR: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type '...'.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.DateTime'.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetDateTime(Int32 ordinal) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs:line 285
   at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetDateTimeOffset(Int32 ordinal) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs:line 288
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 261
   at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

If I comment out the 'gameStart = ...' line from the lambda method, no exception happens. Clearly, it's because the datetime literal of the MinValue is interpreted as a string in the result set. This seems like a severe limitation of the MySQL connector?

Any ideas for a workaround much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround. You can declare a min date variable as `DateTimeOffset? min = DateTimeOffset.MinValue` and use it in the query.

```
context.HostConfigurations.Select (h => new HostStatus {
            id = h.IdHostConfigurations,
            hostname = h.Hostname,
            gameTitle = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation.Title : "-",
            gameStart = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart : min ,
            gameStartFriendly = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart.ToString ("ddd HH:mm") : "-"
        }).ToList ();
```

Comment: Very good, thank you. So selecting a DateTimeOffset parameter will produce a resultset with the correct System.DateTime type. I could not have figured that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have found a workaround for the Connector problem by forcing a local evaluation of the expression:

```
        var hosts = await context.HostConfigurations.Include (h => h.LastGameNavigation).ThenInclude (lg => lg.GameTypeNavigation).ToListAsync ();

        var l = new List<HostStatus> ();

        hosts.ForEach (h => {
            l.Add (new HostStatus {
                id = h.IdHostConfigurations,
                hostname = h.Hostname,
                gameTitle = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.GameTypeNavigation.Title : "-",
                gameStart = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart : DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
                gameStartFriendly = h.IdGamesLast.HasValue ? h.LastGameNavigation.Gamestart.ToString ("ddd HH:mm") : "-",
            });
        });
```